# How to get all rows grouped by value in particular column and make on specific group first in Cursor in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, datatable, grouping

Let's say I have a table with column `city_id`. I need to get a `Cursor` which firstly points to all rows with specific value (that I specify) on that column and then points to rest of rows which are again grouped by `city_id` column?

I have tried:

```
database.query(DATABASE_TABLE_7, columns, null, null, CITY_ID, null, null);
```

but it gave only the last rows of each `city_id` and I'm not able to get rows with specific id first.

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
|  _id  |  city_name  |  city_id  |  ...  |
___________________________________________

|   1   |    "A"      |     1     |  ...  |
|   2   |    "B"      |     2     |  ...  |
|   3   |    "A"      |     1     |  ...  |
|   4   |    "B"      |     2     |  ...  |
|   5   |    "B"      |     2     |  ...  |
|   6   |    "C"      |     3     |  ...  |
|   7   |    "B"      |     2     |  ...  |
|   8   |    "C"      |     3     |  ...  |
```

For example, required city to be first is city "B", the list needs to be like this:

```
1 . "B"
2 . "B"
3 . "B"
4 . "B"
5 . "A"
6 . "A"
7 . "C"
8 . "C"
```

Or

```
1 . "B"
2 . "B"
3 . "B"
4 . "B"
5 . "C"
6 . "C" 
7 . "A"
8 . "A"
```

The order in which the rest of city groups are shown doesn't matter as long as the rows with required city_id are listed first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried UNION?

use a raw query for that (i am not sure for helper query() ) and other helpers method

try this

```
select * from locations where city_id=1 
union 
select * from locations where city_id!=1 order by city_id
```

use any other value as you like (instead of 1)

Comment: I guess `locations` should be replaced with actual table name. Am I right?

Comment: @Marat yes sure, this is just an example, with imaginary table name and fields

Comment: For some reason, `group by` returned only 1 row from each of the groups with different city_id and it is the last one from them. Therefore, I have tried to delete it and got required rows first but rest in order as they are written in table. Moreover, `union` did not work at all. Replaced with `union all` and it worked. Now I need only to group rest of rows. How to do that?

Comment: @Marat i am not sure what do you mean, but that's what group by do. if 10 rows has field x=1 and you are using `group by x` then you will see 1 row only (from the 10)

Comment: Now I understand. But I need to get all of them. Can you tell, please, what are the possible ways to do that?

Comment: @Marat all of what? other rows? with id!=1? if so, then yes, u need to remove `group by` ... however i think it would be better to edit your question, add your table schema, a sample data (5 - 10 rows) then add the expected result. this may help more to understand

Comment: I have added details on the question. Please, take a look at it

Comment: @Marat i have updated the answer, you need to use `order by city_id` on the second select (what miss-guided me) was ur last sentence in the question `which are again grouped by city_id column` that's why i used group by :)

Comment: Hello! I have tried your solution but I get just a sorted list based on `city_id` and not the interested cities first. Just sorted. Maybe I already bothered you, but I really need someone to help me

Comment: @Marat are you having the part `where city_id=...` no way this is ignored by sqlite unless you have something wrong with it

Comment: For some reason it was not working until now. Now I'm getting everything as required. Thank you! I would like to ask you does having a space on both sides of `=` sign make any difference like `where city_id = 1`?

Comment: @Marat good to hear that, and No, space should not be an issue, unless you are dealing with `text` fields, and the space is within the quote, ex `where name = ' Mart'` (note the space between ' and M) this can cause an issue

Comment: Thank you! Will remember all of these for sure!